# How to get access to "CssClass" property for server element isn't WebControl in ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have ordinary div like this:

```
<div id="myCoolElement" runat="server"></div>
```

I want use the construction to set CssClass for myCoolElement like this:

```
myCoolElement.CssClass("mycoolstyle");
```

But CssClass property is supported only for WebControls.

How I can set CssClass for my element without creating WebControl?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this

```
myCoolElement.Attributes["class"] = "mycoolstyle";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
 myCoolElement.Attributes.Add("class", "mycoolstyle");
```